# Ubuntu 22.04 server autoinstall software RAID 1

Tags: raid, mdadm, cloud-init

I'm working on an Ubuntu 22.04 Server autoinstall. So far it works great on a single drive.

But the next step is RAID 1... According to the cloud-init docs this is not supported as part of cloud-init at this time.

Does anyone know of a way to do it, either with scripting inside the user-data or post-install?

Thanks.

Comment: Even if possible it's certainly not recommended. Always prefer to install in a small single and independent drive, not arrays for which you need software support.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the *curtin* documentation for [configuring RAID](https://curtin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/storage.html#raid-command) storage.  The installer (*subiquity*) will use *curtin* to perform the actual storage creation.

Most of the `storage` block in your autoinstall file will be used directly in the configuration created for *curtin*.  As the [autoinstall documentation](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#storage) states

> the installer allows storage configuration to be done using a syntax
> which is a superset of that supported by curtin, described at
> https://curtin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/storage.html.

If you open a shell in the installer environment you can find the configuration that *subiquity* creates for *curtin* at the path `/var/log/installer/subiquity-curtin-install.conf`.